# Date_histogram aggregation not working in custom expression of anomaly detector feature

Tags: opensearch, date-histogram

I am trying to create an anomaly detector in opensearch, as part of it I am trying to implement date_histogram aggregation under custom expression of feature while creating a model.

[image]

But when I try to save the feature it throws me the following error:

"**Validation failed for feature(s) of detector nes-143-external-accountstatus Exceptions: [Feature has an unknown exception caught while executing the feature query: external.accountStatus.keyword] **"

Could you please help me solve this error, this is extremely important for me.